# How can I Change the horizontal Position Of an Element dynamically while using as overflow as scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

On clicking the various label name I'm able to move the "active class dynamically in mobile screens.
Till here it's working fine. But the problem is that when I redirect from other page to the label name coming after the first screen, its active class is implying dynamically. But not able to see on the first screen, unless I scroll it horizontally.

**Expected:** I want my active label part to be visible on the first screen as soon as it's active and  without manual scroll.

[image: Current situation on mobile]
[image: Expected Situation]

```css
.tab_links_parent.common {
  display: inherit;
  background: #2a2044;
  grid-auto-flow: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label:nth-child(1) {
  width: 36%;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label:nth-child(2) {
  width: 44%;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30%;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label:nth-child(4) {
  width: 30%;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab_links_parent common">
  <label class="hand">Payment History</label>
  <label class="hand ">Credit Card Utilisation</label>
  <label class="hand  active">Credit History</label>
  <label class="hand ">Total Accounts</label>
  <label class="hand ">Credit Enquiries</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to use javascript for this. Look into this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,
Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to align a element.

First of all I add `active` class when link is clicked.
Then active element to be aligned centrally.

```
scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center"})
```

```js
var hands= document.querySelectorAll(".hand");
var ele = document.querySelector(".hand.active");
ActiveItem(ele);
function ActiveItem(element){
  for(i=0;i<hands.length;i++){
    hands[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
element.classList.add('active');
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center"});
}
```

```css
.tab_links_parent.common {
  display: inherit;
  background: #2a2044;
  grid-auto-flow: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
}



.tab_links_parent.common label {
  width: 40%;
}

.tab_links_parent.common label.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab_links_parent common">
  <label class="hand " onclick="ActiveItem(this)">Payment History</label>
  <label class="hand "  onclick="ActiveItem(this)">Credit Card Utilisation</label>
  <label class="hand  active "  onclick="ActiveItem(this)">Credit History</label>
  <label class="hand "  onclick="ActiveItem(this)">Total Accounts</label>
  <label class="hand "  onclick="ActiveItem(this)">Credit Enquiries</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Matthew Watts Thanks a lot. It really means a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping with the code. It really means a lot. :)